# Carousel title disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm really new to bootstrap and web development overall and I don't know what to do. I have made a carousel for the website we had to make for our computer science class, but then I added the title and now, when I shrink the site to mobile size, the title just disappears. Here is my carousel HTML:

```
<div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-prev"></div>
        <div class="carousel-next"></div>
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="christmas.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="christmas2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="christmas3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5 class="myText">Our shop</h5>
            <p>Browse our catalog and discover great discounts</p>          
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .carousel-image {
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .full-screen {
          background-size: cover;
          background-position: center;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .z-index-1 {
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .z-index-2 {
            z-index: 2;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%
        }

        .myText {
            font-size: 70px;
            -webkit-text-stroke: 4px red;
        }

        .controls {
            margin-top: 0%;
        }

        .myHR {
            border-width: 4px;
            border-color: white;
            margin-left: 30%;
            margin-right: 30%; 
        }

        .carousel-paragraph {
            font-size: 25px;
        }

        .carousel-caption {
            top: 40%;
            position: absolute;
        }
```

And this is my javascript:

```
var $item = $('.carousel-item'); 
        var $wHeight = $(window).height();
        $item.eq(0).addClass('active');
        $item.height($wHeight); 
        $item.addClass('full-screen');

        $('.carousel img').each(function() {
          var $src = $(this).attr('src');
          var $color = $(this).attr('data-color');
          $(this).parent().css({
            'background-image' : 'url(' + $src + ')',
            'background-color' : $color
          });
          $(this).remove();
        });

        $(window).on('resize', function (){
          $wHeight = $(window).height();
          $item.height($wHeight);
        });

        $('.carousel').carousel({
          interval: 6000,
          pause: "false"
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just removed the d-none class from my title division. It seems to work for me.

```
<div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
    <h5 class="myText">Our shop</h5>
    <p>Browse our catalog and discover great discounts</p>          
</div>
```